# splitting content of a pyspark dataframe column and aggregating them into new columns

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to extract and split the data within  pyspark dataframe column, following which, aggregate it into a new columns.

Input Table.

```
+--+-----------+
|id|description|
+--+-----------+
|1 |  3:2,3|2:1|
|2 |  2        |
|3 |  2:12,16  |
|4 |  3:2,4,6  |
|5 |  2        |
|6 |  2:3,7|2:3|
+--------------+
```

Desired Output.

```
+--+-----------+-------+-----------+
|id|description|sum_emp|org_changed|
+--+-----------+-------+-----------+
|1 |  3:2,3|2:1| 5     | 3         |
|2 |  2        | 2     | 0         |        
|3 |  2:12,16  | 2     | 2         |
|4 |  3:2,4,6  | 3     | 3         |
|5 |  2        | 2     | 0         |
|6 |  2:3,7|2:3| 4     | 3         |
+--------------+-------+-----------+
```

Before the ":", values ought to be added. The values post the ":" are to be counted. The | marks the shift in the record(can be ignored)

Some data points are as long as 2:3,4,5|3:4,6,3|4:3,7,8
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Scenario Explained:

Considering the 6th id for example. The 6 refers to a biz unit id.  The 'Description' column describes the team within that given unit.

Now for the meaning of the values 2:3,7|2:3 are as follows: 
1)Fist 2 followed by 3&7 = there are 2 folks in the team and one of them has been in another org for 3 years and for 7 years (perhaps its the second guys first company)
2)Second 2 followed by 3 = there are 2 folks again in a sub team, and 1 person has spent 3 years in another org.

Desired output:
sum_emp = total number of employees in that given biz unit.
org_changed  = total number of organizations folks in that biz unit have changed.

Comment: can you please quote what is your input and expected output format ? its bit confusing.

Comment: Thank You for your response. The input column (description) is a string. Expected output format for sum_emp and org_changed in an Int. I hope, this adds clarity.

Comment: you mean to say, first table is ur input and second table is expected output ?

Comment: oh yes, my bad. Missed to add that. Have edited it now :) Thank You for pointing that out.

Comment: On what basis, you arriving to description ,sum_emp , org_changed  on expected output? can you pls explain the logic bit clearly ?

Comment: Please explain things like, how did `2,3` and `:1` appear in the first row. And then in the first row, `sum_emp` looks like the sum of whatever is after `3:` but what about the other column? And then in the third row of your desired output `sum_emp` of `2:12,16` results in `2`. Shouldn't it be 28? Please provide a thorough explanation of how you're arriving to the expected output table. Thanks!

Comment: Thank You for your response Balaji and philantrovert. The initial description was vague, my bad. I have explained the datapoint in detail. Thank You.

Comment: for the first 1 id, input dataframe has `3|2` but the output dataframe has `3:2,3|2:1` how is that? similar is the case for 6th id. Can you explain that?

Comment: Oops, thats a typo. Updated, Thank You for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's create our dataframe:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize([[1,"3:2,3|2:1"],
                    [2,"2"],
                    [3,"2:12,16"],
                    [4,"3:2,4,6"],
                    [5,"2"],
                    [6,"2:3,7|2:3"]]), 
    ["id","description"])

    +---+-----------+
    | id|description|
    +---+-----------+
    |  1|  3:2,3|2:1|
    |  2|          2|
    |  3|    2:12,16|
    |  4|    3:2,4,6|
    |  5|          2|
    |  6|  2:3,7|2:3|
    +---+-----------+
```

First we'll split the records and explode the resulting array so we only have one record per line:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf

df = df.withColumn(
    "record", 
    psf.explode(psf.split("description", '\|'))
)

    +---+-----------+-------+
    | id|description| record|
    +---+-----------+-------+
    |  1|  3:2,3|2:1|  3:2,3|
    |  1|  3:2,3|2:1|    2:1|
    |  2|          2|      2|
    |  3|    2:12,16|2:12,16|
    |  4|    3:2,4,6|3:2,4,6|
    |  5|          2|      2|
    |  6|  2:3,7|2:3|  2:3,7|
    |  6|  2:3,7|2:3|    2:3|
    +---+-----------+-------+
```

Now we'll split records into the number of players and a list of years:

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "record", 
    psf.split("record", ':')
).withColumn(
    "nb_players", 
    psf.col("record")[0]
).withColumn(
    "years", 
    psf.split(psf.col("record")[1], ',')
)

    +---+-----------+----------+----------+---------+
    | id|description|    record|nb_players|    years|
    +---+-----------+----------+----------+---------+
    |  1|  3:2,3|2:1|  [3, 2,3]|         3|   [2, 3]|
    |  1|  3:2,3|2:1|    [2, 1]|         2|      [1]|
    |  2|          2|       [2]|         2|     null|
    |  3|    2:12,16|[2, 12,16]|         2| [12, 16]|
    |  4|    3:2,4,6|[3, 2,4,6]|         3|[2, 4, 6]|
    |  5|          2|       [2]|         2|     null|
    |  6|  2:3,7|2:3|  [2, 3,7]|         2|   [3, 7]|
    |  6|  2:3,7|2:3|    [2, 3]|         2|      [3]|
    +---+-----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Finally, we want to sum for each `id` the number of players and the length of `years`:

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "years_size", 
    psf.when(psf.size("years") > 0, psf.size("years")).otherwise(0)
).groupby("id").agg(
    psf.first("description").alias("description"), 
    psf.sum("nb_players").alias("sum_emp"), 
    psf.sum("years_size").alias("org_changed")
).sort("id").show()

    +---+-----------+-------+-----------+
    | id|description|sum_emp|org_changed|
    +---+-----------+-------+-----------+
    |  1|  3:2,3|2:1|    5.0|          3|
    |  2|          2|    2.0|          0|
    |  3|    2:12,16|    2.0|          2|
    |  4|    3:2,4,6|    3.0|          3|
    |  5|          2|    2.0|          0|
    |  6|  2:3,7|2:3|    4.0|          3|
    +---+-----------+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: It worked like a charm!! Thank You so much Marie :) 
You saved my day.

Comment: It's no problem mur, don't forget to mark it  as solved :)